# Visual Studio 2012 C++ How to add compiler option in NMake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am currently modifying on a open-source project to suit my own need, however, the project to be built (or compiler) requires me to add a /EHsc option to cl.exe

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to work on the project. I have been searching long enough but I cannot find the solution still.

Is it possible to add a flag via MS Visual Studio 2012? Because I saw the output log displaying that compiler (cl.exe) compiled with various flag in this project such as /nologo /c /WX.

How can I add the options to cl.exe with this IDE?

Project working on : [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html)

[Edit #1] After reading the first answer provided below, this is the screen I got, it doesn't seem there is an option to do so.
[image: Conf]

Comment: Ah, this is an NMake project. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** From the screenshot you posted, it seems the SumatraPDF project is [NMake-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx).

Therefore, you will have to add `/EHsc` to the build command line, using the NMake property page described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87h6614.aspx), or edit the Makefile directly.

**Original, misguided answer follows:**

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development
>   environment**
>
> 1. Open the project's **Property Pages** dialog box. For details, see [How to: Open Project Property Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e79xc5h1.aspx).
> 2. Select the **C/C++** folder.
> 3. Select the **Code Generation** property page.
> 4. Modify the **Enable C++ Exceptions** property.
>
> Or, set **Enable C++ Exceptions** to **No**, and then on the **Command Line**
>   property page, in the **Additional Options** box, add the compiler option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the closest screen I can ever get is VC++ Directories and it doesn't seem to be option mentioned in your answer, I will update my question shortly